# Format specifier for data type "short" in JAVA

Tags: java

please tell what format specifier is used for "short" data type in java? Like %d is used for integer %s is used for string.

Answer (score 1):

There is none. `short` is just a 16-bit integer, so use `%d`.

If you want an *unsigned* `short`, use this code.

```
short s;
int unsignedShort = ((int) s) & 0xFFFF;
```

and use that value with `%d`.

Answer (score 1):

From [primitive data types](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/java/nutsandbolts/datatypes.html):

> `short`: The `short` data type is a 16-bit signed two's complement integer. It has a minimum value of -32,768 and a maximum value of 32,767 (inclusive). As with `byte`, the same guidelines apply: you can use a `short` to save memory in large arrays, in situations where the memory savings actually matters.

A short is an integer, so using `%d` is the correct way.

Answer (score 0):

You can use %d as if it were an integer.